# How to add shutdown option to the Ubuntu lock screen?

Tags: shutdown, lock-screen

Some times I want to just shut the computer down rather than to enter the password and continue. Even if that would be someone else willing to shut my computer down while I'm away he should better be able to do this peacefully rather than by just switching the power off. Can I add shutdown to the lock screen menu for such cases?

Update for those saying it's there: I use the standard Ubuntu 15.10 (not any kind of "spin-off" like KUbuntu nor a derivative like Mint or ElementaryOS) and all I have got in the upper-right corner gear menu is "Switch Account", "Guest Session" and "Suspend".

Comment: Ubuntu's default lockscreen does have this option, I have it on my 14.04, pretty sure 15.10 also does.  What version do you use ?  And you do know about the `sysrq` keys , right ?

Comment: top right corner,  a gear/power icon, click for a menu - in it is shutdown. unless you are using something other than "Ubuntu"

Comment: @Serg no, what's there about sysrq? It seems to do notink on my lock screen and it calls gnome-screenshot in normal mode (yes, I'm sure I'm pressing SysRq, not PrintScreen (these are separate keys on my laptop keyboard ))

Comment: @Mateo I use standard Ubuntu 15.10, it's not there.

Comment: wow, strange  they did remove it... I have one 15.10 system and it dosn't have it either, but the other versions do

Comment: @Ivan If it's not there , you should report it as a bug, because it is supposed to be there. As for Sysrq, it's used to safely shutdown or reboot a system when it becomes unresponsive, but can be used to just plain shutdown it as well. Hold Atl+Sysrq, and then press one by one r-e-i-s-u-o. If you replace o with b , that's reboot, o is shutdown

Comment: @Mateo they didn't remove it. I have 15.10 in VM and it's there

Comment: @Serg most of reisub was disabled for "safety" http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2252485

Comment: @Mateo  I am sceptical of that. Have you tried it on your 15.10 ?

Comment: **CLOSE VOTERS** : please retract your votes, this post clearly asks a specific question. Do not close !

Comment: @Ivan can you please copy the contents of `/usr/share/glib-2.0/schemas/com.canonical.unity-greeter.gschema.xml` file and post it to `paste.ubuntu.com` ? Once pasted, please provide the link to it

Comment: I have the same problem as OP, on an Ubuntu 14.04. And yes I know the differences between Kubuntu, Lubuntu etc. and I am using Ubuntu.

Answer (score 2):

You actually don't need to add shutdown to that menu.

You can click on **Switch Account** and you'll have **Shutdown** on the new screen's menu.

That way, it's possible to shut the computer down without logging in first. That works on ubuntu 14.04 LTS and 16.04 LTS.

Comment: 19.10 - not working if you have one user

Answer (score 0):

I've found for v18.04.4 that it only had the pause option, until I clicked the user. When it asks for a password instead of typing one, I just click the top right menu again and it now contains the power off icon.

Comment: That doesn't seem to be the case on 20.04.