# How to shut down from lockscreen in 22.04?

Tags: shutdown, 22.04, lock-screen

I found [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/699871/how-to-add-shutdown-option-to-the-ubuntu-lock-screen) but it doesn't seem applicable.

In Ubuntu 22.04, the power icon in the top right corner stays there when the screen is locked, but isn't active. Is there any way to shut down the system cleanly without logging in first?

Comment: I am sorry if I am asking wrong.. you mean lock screen or login screen?

Comment: I mean the lock screen.

Comment: Ok, if yet all it is possible, it works like killing all the open windows and work. I mean force shutdown, is that Ok or not?

Comment: I just checked. When the screen is locked using the pull-down menu at the top right corner, the same menu only has one item in the "Logout, Restart, PowerOff" sub-menu. That item is **Suspend**. There are no other options. I think this is by design. You are not supposed to power off or restart your computer from the lock screen.

Comment: Upon reflection, I can see why that would be sensible to the developers: You don't want random folks walking past to have the power to destroy all the logged-in users' unsaved work.

Comment: @user535733 but they do have that power. All they have to do is turn off the machine. I'd rather they shut it down cleanly than just power it off.

Comment: @user68186 while the screen is locked that menu seems completely unresponsive.

Comment: @MarkReed I can't reproduce your problem. The menu works on my computer. It shows only "Suspend".

Comment: @user68186 interesting. You're on a stock 22.04 install? amd64? I've got a vanilla install from the iso, with no customization outside my shell. Heck, my desktop background is still the jellyfish.  In the upper right I have a capsule that has three icons (network, volume, power) but is just one big button that brings up a menu containing items for all three functions. When I lock the screen, that big button is still there, but nothing happens when I click on it.

Comment: @MarkReed Mine is stock 22.04 install, AMD64. Here is a photo of the lock-screen menu: https://i.imgur.com/5GQspHp.jpeg  You may want to upload a picture like this and add a link to your question.

Comment: I mean, I can take a pic but there's nothing to see except my mouse cursor hovering over the menu widget. It's hard to tell from a photo that I'm furiously clicking and nothing's happening. :) It doesn't even highlight (the way the circle around switch-user does) or anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The network/volume/power menu is completely unresponsive when the screen is locked, which seems to be a problem specific to my setup rather than a general one. In case anyone else runs into it, however: the "switch user" icon in the bottom right takes you to the main login screen. From *that* screen, the power menu is active again, and you can suspend, restart, or cleanly power down the machine without having to log in.